# app crashed in GifImageView while changing device "date and time" on "Settings" menu

Tags: android, android-imageview, gif

I'm using the following project to show the gif image in the android application. https://github.com/vivekgidmare/giffiledecoder. It works fine. But when I'm trying to change the date and time on Settings option, it crashes the app.

**Error says that:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-7350
java.lang.RuntimeException: Gif thread leaked, fix your code at {packagename}.ui.gifview.GifImageView.backgroundThread(GifImageView.java:296)
at {packagename}.ui.gifview.GifImageView.access$100(GifImageView.java:23)
at {packagename}.ui.gifview.GifImageView$2.run(GifImageView.java:144)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

**Error points at:**

```
if (System.currentTimeMillis() > startTime + 4 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
throw new RuntimeException("Gif thread leaked, fix your code"); // error pointing line
```